# ASP Classic substring issue

Tags: asp-classic, substring

I'm pretty new to ASP CLassic and struggling to get this working. Essentially I have result sets from two database queries, and need to compare some values between them.

I'm trying to substring into one of the fields on the result set without success.

```
jMax = ubound(arrProject, 2)
    for j = 0 to jMax

        // Get List of Users and their Group Permissions. 
        strCommand = "SELECT [US_USERNAME],[US_GROUP] FROM [" & arrProject(2,j) & "].[td].[USERS] "
        objCommand.CommandText = strCommand
        Set objUsers = objCommand.Execute()

        // Get a list of the Group Names associated to the Project
        strCommand = "SELECT [GR_GROUP_ID],[GR_GROUP_NAME] FROM [" & arrProject(2,j) & "].[td].[GROUPS] "
        objCommand.CommandText = strCommand
        set objGroups = objCommand.Execute()


        // Determine the Group ID 
        strGroupID = "x"
        objGroups.moveFirst             
        Do While strGroupID = "x" 
            If objGroups("GR_GROUP_NAME") = "some value" Then
                strGroupID = objGroups("GR_GROUP_ID")
            End If
        objGroups.moveNext
        Loop

        // 
        objUsers.moveFirst  
        Do While (Not objUsers.EOF)
            If objUsers("US_GROUP").substring(strGroupID,1) = "1" Then
                response.write objUsers("US_GROUP") & vbCrLf
            End If
        ObjUsers.moveNext
        Loop

    next
```

Its failing at the point where I'm trying to use the substring.

Initially I tried to use an array rather than substring in, but had difficulty trying to re-create the array in subsequent passes through the loop.

```
arrUserGroups = objUsers.GetRows(,,Array("US_GROUP"))
```

So I ended up with this.

Any thoughts as to what I'm missing here would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you want `InStr`, not SubString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the sample may be overly complex for your question, which may be quite simple. Plus, I don't think sufficient information is provided because we don't know what your database records/fields look like. This makes it difficult to guess what you're trying to do. But in the end I don't think "what you're trying to do" is important; instead what's important is figuring out what exactly is tripping you up.

I would be looking at `InStr()` if you're trying to find the first occurrence of one string in another string. I would look at `Mid()` if you're trying to extract a substring from one string to compare to another.

Comment: strGroupFlag = Left(objUsers("US_GROUP"),(objGroups("GR_GROUP_ID") + 1)) 
    strGroupFlag = Right(strGroupFlag,1) 

However your MID suggestion looks to be what I was after -            strGroupFlag = Mid(objUsers("US_GROUP"),(objGroups("GR_GROUP_ID") + 1)) Thanks